# Les « Gafa, GAFA, GAFAM, BATX, Natu » : la géométrie variable de l'acronyme ou l'air du temps ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, acronymes

Dans deux articles ([1](http://www.lapresse.ca/techno/internet/201707/06/01-5113718-publicite-numerique-le-monde-et-le-figaro-sallient-face-a-google-et-facebook.php), [2](http://www.lapresse.ca/techno/201707/10/01-5114821-face-a-facebook-et-google-les-medias-americains-veulent-sunir.php)) on traite de la concentration de la publicité numérique et du contrôle de l'information sur Internet, et de solutions envisagées pour y remédier ; dans le premier cas il s'agit du contexte des médias français et dans le deuxième, d'éditeurs de presse américains. Dans le premier article on y retrouve les propos d'un dirigeant d'entreprise qui dit :

> Aujourd'hui le marché publicitaire a explosé et est contrôlé
>   massivement par les GAFA.
>
> [ Louis Dreyfus, directeur général du groupe *Le Monde*
>   (Bergé-Niel-Pigasse) ]

Dans le deuxième article on n'y fait pas allusion. Sur Wikipédia on a un article sur les [*géants du Web*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9ants_du_Web) (précédé de plusieurs avertissements), où l'on distingue les *géants du Web* des *géants du numérique* selon certains critères comme la taille et la contribution d'une architecture de base de données (possiblement en [rupture](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) avec certains de ses principes classiques). On y lit que :

> Les actuels géants sont ainsi américains et surnommés GAFA ou GAFAM,
>   acronyme constitué des géants les plus connus (Google, Apple,
>   Facebook, Amazon, Microsoft) ; ou encore chinois et surnommés BATX
>   pour Baidu, Alibaba, Tencent et Xiaomi ; ou bien les Natu (Netflix,
>   Airbnb, Tesla, Uber).

L'acronyme est composé de la première lettre du nom de ces sociétés en ordre décroissant d'importance ou de part de marché semble-t-il, et il aurait déjà eu le temps de changer (GAFA**M**). On établit des parallèles avec les termes *Big Four*, les *Big Five*, ou encore « The Five », nous apprend encore [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gafa). La mécanique de formation de cet acronyme fait en sorte qu'il peut changer avec le temps, selon le classement des entreprises, voire devenir méconnaissable, et son orthographe semble de ce fait imprévisible.

---

- Comment qualifie-t-on un [*acronyme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronymie) dont les composantes (ou leur ordre)
  peuvent changer avec le temps selon un facteur comme la part de marché d'une entreprise,
  est-ce simplement l'emploi de l'acronyme qui « évolue », est-ce un
  procédé mnémotechnique ? Ce genre de procédé de formation de
  l'acronyme est-il récent (à quant remonte le premier emploi
  de *GAFA*), et le cas échéant a-t-on d'autres exemples ?
- Dans l'article on trouve un emploi avec la majuscule initiale puis
  les minuscules (*Gafa*), ou tout en majuscules (*GAFA*) : lequel
  préfère-t-on, le voit-on davantage comme un *sigle* ou un *nom* ou
  s'agit-il de deux emplois distincts, et ai-je raison de penser qu'on
  prononce ça comme un mot (comme *gaffe* mais avec un *a*) et non
  qu'on l'épelât ?
- Est-ce uniquement du vocabulaire [*financier*](http://www.agefi.com/quotidien-agefi/europe-monde/detail/edition/2015-08-07/article/les-valeurs-natu-netflix-airbnb-tesla-et-uber-contestent-la-puissance-des-gafa-google-amazon-facebook-et-apple-404247.html), ou un truc usuel
  qu'on rencontre couramment et qu'on reconnaît immédiatement dans une
  conversation, ce genre d'acronymie est-il généralement associé au monde des affaires ; qu'est-ce qu'ajoute l'acronyme *Gafa/GAFA* à *géants
  du numérique* ?

Comment: De mon point vue c'est surtout une méthode rapide pour citer ces entreprises. J'aurais tendance à ranger cela dans une catégorie 'mot à la mode'. Son utilisation n'est pas cantonnée au domaine financier, dans le domaine informatique on cite souvent GAFA/GAFAM, principalement parceque Google, Amazon et Microsoft font l'avancée technique des plateformes 'cloud' et Facebook et Apple pour leur gestion de données à très grande échelle et les avancées technologiques dans le développement de logiciels

Comment: @Tensibai Merci, n'hésitez pas à répondre. Je ne sais pas si vous êtes familier avec un tour comme _les [nom d'une entreprise comme substantif] de ce monde_, c'est le prototype pour qualifier un ensemble de sociétés de même catégorie ou envergure. Ce sont des trucs bien plus centrés sur le nom alors que le nombre (comme _Five_) est plus pragmatique. Mais je comprends de ce que vous dites que ce n'est pas tant le pragmatisme ou le concept qu'on recherche que de précisément cibler avec une méthode rapide. Enfin ce que vous expliquez en fin de comm., ce sont des sous-cat. ds. _g. du numérique_ ?

Comment: Je vais avoir un peu de mal à sourcer ce point de vue malheureusement, ça reste juste mon opinion (d'où le format de commentaire et pas en réponse). En fin de commentaire j'essayais d'illustrer la variabilité, je ne sais pas si l'ordre est vraiment défini en fonction de la taille de l'entreprise ou juste pour en faciliter la prononciation en revanche.

Answer (score 4):

Je vais tenter une réponse mais je ne garantie pas sa véracité.
Les termes GAFA et GAFAM sont bien des acronymes. Je lis GAFA depuis au moins 5 ans dans la presse spécialisée (on trouve des articles de 2012 en parlant déjà). Ce terme a évolué vers GAFAM avec la monté en puissance de Microsoft suite à l'effort gigantesque de ce dernier pour s'imposer dans le marché de "l'informatique dans les nuages".
Google Trend montre une augmentation des recherches sur les GAFAM depuis 2016 et une augmentation continue des recherches sur le mot GAFA (attention le terme GAFA est associé à beaucoup d'autre choses) depuis 2013.
Concernant l'orthographe, [les acronymes et sigles sont généralement écrits en majuscules. Lorsque l'un d'eux devient très utilisé, il peut se transformer en nom commun](http://www.les-abreviations.com/definitions.html) (ex: sida : Syndrome de l'Immuno-Déficience Acquise) et s'écrire alors comme n'importe quel nom commun avec une majuscule en début de phrase, sinon en minuscule. Il s'agit donc de déterminer si GAFAM constitue encore un acronyme ou un mot désignant les géants du web.

Concernant l'ordre des lettres je pense que cela a une double visée, à la fois classer les acteurs (si cela est possible) et surtout générer un acronyme avec une prononciation simple et pas un sigle qu'on ne retient pas.
Par exemple, concernant les GAFAM, je ne sais pas comment ils sont classés mais ça n'est [ni par capitalisation boursière](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_entreprises_par_capitalisation_boursi%C3%A8re#2018) [ni par revenu](https://fr.statista.com/infographie/12778/les-revenus-mirobolants-des-gafam/). Gageons que si les journalistes parlaient des AGMAF, moins de gens auraient retenu le terme.

Enfin concernant l'emploi de ce mot, je l'ai personnellement entendu en premier chez les activistes des droits sur Internet et je pense que leur but était de sensibiliser et rendre plus visible les GAFAM.
Ce terme en a petit à petit inspiré d'autres que les journalistes ont inventés pour parler de AirBnB ou Netflix, ou encore des géants chinois du web chinois.
Je ne crois pas mais ne peux pas confirmer que ces termes soient particulièrement liés au monde de la finance.
À mon humble avis, il s'agit d'un terme qui sonne bien permettant de désigner facilement un groupement d'entreprises ayant en commun certaines choses (comme leur présence dans le cloud, l'invention d'un nouveau modèle économique ou encore le partage de valeurs managériales...).

**Edit:**
Pour répondre à votre dernière question: géants du web ne signifie pas GAFAM, mais les GAFAM font partis des géants du web. L'acronyme sert à désigner 5 entreprises qui partagent certains traits (le cloud, la collecte massive de donnée, la publicité, le profilage, la recherche en informatique, l'évasion fiscale...)

Comment: Au contraire GAFAM a tendance à disparaître au profit de GAFA (cf "c dans l'air").

Comment: Je ne ferai pas confiance au service publique français pour parler de technologie

Comment: Le service publique ne fait que retransmettre un débat. Les participants sont variés et ne sont majoritairement pas affiliés à ce service.